# Solving $Ax=B$: what's wrong with this linear algebra argument?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

With $K>L$ and assuming that we are working with real variables, suppose that $B$ is $K\times 1$ and $A$ is $K\times L$ with full column rank. I'm trying to find $x$ ($L\times 1$) satisfying:
$$
Ax=B.\tag{i}
$$
There are more equations than unknowns $(K>L)$ so there is no guarantee that we can find a solution. Yet, I cannot find what is wrong with this argument: pre-multiply both sides of (i) with $A'$:
$$
A'Ax=A'B\implies x=(A'A)^{-1}A'B.\tag{ii}
$$
The matrix $A'A$ is invertible because $A$ has full column rank. Could you please explain why (ii) doesn't work? I can see that if $x=(A'A)^{-1}A'B$, then
$$
Ax=A(A'A)^{-1}A'B
$$
which doesn't readily simplify to $B$. But is this enough to say (ii) is invalid? If (ii) doesn't work, how could I solve (i) or show that no solution exists?

Comment: What matrix is $A'$?

Comment: @DavidPeterson It's the transpose of $A$.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse Perhaps this helps.

Comment: Sorry for another comment. I am not really sure I understand you and am a bit in a rush, but I think $A'$ does not induce an injective map. Thus Ax and B might be different while after multiplication with A' they are equal.

Comment: @quid: thanks for your second comment.

Comment: David's (+1) solution explains the logic. I will give a numerical example to make sure that you see where the problem is. With $A={1\choose 1}$ and $B={2\choose 1}$ you have the impossible system: $x=2$ AND $x=1$. Your idea to premultiply by $A'$ then gives as a consequence the system $x+x=2+1$ or $2x=3$. From that you would solve $x=3/2$, and realize that something went very wrong :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks Jyrki. The example makes things really clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difficulty is really logic, not algebra.  It is true that
$$\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}A\\x=\\b\quad\Rightarrow\quad A'A\\x=A'\\b\ ,$$
but it is not true that
$$\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}A\\x=\\b\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad A'A\\x=A'\\b\ .$$
You have shown correctly that *if there is a solution* it is $\\x=(A'A)^{-1}A'\\b$, but this does not mean that there actually is a solution.

Comment: Oh I see. Great point!